# Hidden sites description should be clearer

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page, hidden-communities

What does the header on "hidden communities" mean?

> The following communities are hidden and are only visible to you and moderators

What mods? This site? That site? Any site? It should be clearer so we all understand it.

Comment: Think it's pretty clear: moderators of the current site where the profile is in. In the network profile everyone can see all communities anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following communities are hidden and are only visible to you and
>   moderators

So, it's only visible to "moderators".

> What mods? This site? That site? Any site? It should be clearer so we
>   all understand it.

"Moderators".

For example, if you see that message on *Server Fault*, a "moderator" on *Stack Overflow* is not a "moderator" on *Server Fault*, and so the moderator from Stack Overflow is not a "moderator" in context of that message on Server Fault.

Unless they are *also* a moderator on Server Fault, but then they are by definition "a moderator on Server Fault" and thus are a "moderator" in context of that message.

Comment: So a moderator on the current site I'm using?

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy Yes. A "moderator" is defined "per site". A moderator of a site can be *not* a moderator on every other site apart from that one. The message on that one site relates to that moderator, but not on all other sites.